# How create class errors?

Tags: java

I create service and I need create class MyErrors (not exception)

My web method returned or data or error, example response "`#45#Not valid login or password.`"

`#` - is a flag that says an error has occurred
`45` - code error.

example use error class:

```
int returnValue = ExistLogin(login);
if (returnValue==0) {
    return Registaration(login, name, password);
} else if(returnValue==1) {
    return Errors.LOGIN_ALREADY_EXISTS.ToString();
}
else return Errors.ConvertToString(returnValue);
```

Errors.LOGIN_ALREADY_EXISTS - return number `<-1`

Errors.LOGIN_ALREADY_EXISTS - return string `#-1#Error bla bla bla`

how best to create a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Java `enum` for this:

```
public enum Errors {
    LOGIN_ALREADY_EXISTS(-1, "The username is already in use."),
    UNKNOWN(0, "Unknown");

    private final int errorCode;
    private final String message;

    private Errors(int errorCode, String message) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "#" + errorCode + "#" + message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For that usage the return statement must be of the same type. In your case this it's not. I would test if the user exists and and then decide wether to return an error code or message in the service or the registration. And make a boolean out of your test variable.

```
ResponseObject o;//wether SOAP, RPC-XML, JSON, XML

if(ExistLogin(login)/*must return boolean*/)
{
    o = createExistAnswerForService(login);
}
else
{
    o = createUserAddedAnswerForService(login, name, password);
}
return o;
```

In the response you can give the user information if the call was successful or not. I won't create an error class since it is no error but a validation fault. Always use error to catch them not to communicate with the user. Otherwise code will be confusing to others.